# Add to usings doesn't appear as resolve option in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, using

In Visual Studio 2013, when I tried to use the Directory class of the System.IO namespace, before adding the System.IO as a reference , I used to press 'Ctrl+.' and an option would say 'using System.IO;'.

This option doesn't appear in my Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. Instead I get these options:
[image: Where's the add to Using option?]

Anyone an idea how I can get that 'using' option in this version as well?

Comment: Normally it's there. Do you have some steps to reproduce this ? What type of project do you use ?

Comment: I am using a Windows Form project at the moment, yet I saw this happening in different applications. So I think it might be a setting, but I can't find it..

Comment: Did they change the icon for the feature in 2015? Because I don't recognize the light bulb; you should check to make sure you don't have installed something like Resharper or other tool that overrides the default VS behavior.